# Need help executing these commands ACTION_DELETE

Tags: android

I have installed an application on INTEL Oaktrail tab and I need to uninstall it now. I was going through this forum and I found that in package manager if you execute ACTION_DELETE your installed program gets uninstalled. Is this correct?
If yes can someone tell me exact steps on how to execute this command (which path/directory and exact command to run)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to uninstall an app from your android device try the following code:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.any.app");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks Dinesh, but where should I run this from? I am clueless

Comment: Thats on you. When you want to uninstall the app(Like on some button click then include this code in **OnClickListener** of the button).Try this. But one thing you want to uninstall an app programatically...am I right...?

Comment: I am guessing that you aren't a developer and simply want to uninstall an app. This is a Q&A site for developers. Please consult your phone's manual or navigate your way through the settings screen to uninstall an app by hand.

Comment: If you want to do it mannually from device just follow the steps.... **Setting->Application->Manage Application->your app** . Click on it and uninstall it.

Comment: ok, can you also please tell me how to programatically undo it too

Comment: ok, I will rephrase it. I got how to uninstall it. Once i install the app, where should I look (path) to see if the app is successfully installed and see details about the app.

Comment: Follow this:  **Setting->Application->Manage Application->your app** and check your app details.

Comment: **android system info** download this app from android market. This is a very good app and give all the info of your device ,app,task manager etc.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, you were of great help.